# API, angularJS, to get datas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I never done angularJS from all my life and i am lost.

So i have done this file, to obtain datas from an api with a filter of time.

forecast.js

```
        (function() {

angular.module('application').factory('Forecast', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

  var ApiAddr = "api.com/";


  forecast.getResults = function(timeStart, timeEnd){
    // We map application varaible names with API param names
    var httpParams = {
      type: "global",
      time: "minute",
      tsmin: timeStart,
      tsmax: timeEnd
    };
    return $http.get(apiAddr, {
      params: httpParams,
      cache: true
    }).then(function(data){
      return data;
    },
            function(response){
              console.log(
          "HTTP request "+ApiAddr+
          " (with parameters tsmin="+httpParams.tsmin+", tsmax="+httpParams.tsmax+
          ", type="+httpParams.type+", time="+httpParams.time+
          (httpParams.motive ? ", motive="+httpParams.motive : "")+
          (httpParams.vector ? ", vector="+httpParams.vector : "")+
          (httpParams.media ? ", media="+httpParams.media : "")+
          ") failed with "+response.status
        );
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
    );
}];
```

But i have no idea to make a controller adapter to this. What type of controller i can do ?
Every exemple are based on a fixed json file, with no parameters.

Moreover, i want, in HTML to imput the time filter, but i have totaly no idea of what to do for this. The example i have seen were to get datas, no to send.

Ps : I have made 2 days of research about this, i have never done front end programming in my life.

Comment: you want to send `httpParams` to you api?

Comment: yes. and the datas (time) come from an HTML page, and i want controller to manipulate the obtained data in order to output it on the HTML page.

Comment: Note that [success / error](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) are obsolete and are not only no longer supported they are no longer included if using angular 1.6 or later. Instead use `then` with one or both callbacks.

Comment: As far as what to do with your `Forecast factory` I recommend you use a component and not a controller. See [component documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

Comment: I will edit my code right now.

Comment: Is this the good edits ?

Comment: @TotorAndMimine You wanna build a component or u want to write a controller to access this service?

Comment: The best thing to acces datas, display in in the HTML page. And the input datas in the HTML, must go to the API in order to obtain the datas.
Sorry i am totally a beginner in front end programming, my questions can look stupids...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function() {

  angular.module('application', [])
    .factory('Forecast', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
      var apiaddress = 'api.com';
      var forecast = {};

      forecast.getResults = function(timeStart, timeEnd) {
        // We map application varaible names with API param names
        var httpParams = {
          type: "global",
          time: "minute",
          tsmin: timeStart,
          tsmax: timeEnd
        };
        return $http.get(apiaddress, {
          params: httpParams,
          cache: true
        }).then(function(result) {
          return result.data;
        });
      };

      return forecast;

    }])
    .controller('SampleCtrl', ['$scope', 'Forecast', function($scope, Forecast) {
      $scope.forecastReport = '';

      $scope.getForecast = function() {
        Forecast.getResults($scope.timeStart, $scope.timeEnd)
          .then(function(report) {
            $scope.result = report;
          }).catch(function(err) {
            $scope.result = '';
            console.error('Unable to fetch forecast report: ' + err);
          });
      };
    }]);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="application" ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
  <label>Time Start:
  <input type="text" ng-model="timeStart"/></label>
    <label>Time End:
  <input type="text" ng-model="timeEnd"/></label>
  
  <button ng-click="getForecast()">Get Forecast</button>
  <hr/>
  <div>
  <b>Forecast Result:</b>
  </div>
  <pre>{{forecastReport | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: @TotorAndMimine Can u mark as resolved. if you are satisfied with this answer

Comment: Just a little problem : in the controller, you initialize timeStart and timeEnd, or i want the value inputed in the html page.
I have made something like that :
input type="datetime-local" ng-model='timeStart'></input>

Comment: Updated. Now `Forecast.getResults` takes the value passed from input fields

Comment: In the html page, how to access the data of the Json ?
If i write {{forecastReport.attribute1}}, it writes nothing...

Comment: can u paste your sample response here?

Answer (score 0):

Just inject the factory into your controller like this:

```
var app = angular.module('application');
app.controller('myController',
      ['$scope', 'Forecast', function($scope, Forecast) { /* access to Forecast*/}]);
```

Or with a component (cleaner):

```
app.component('myComponentCtrl', {
       templateUrl: 'template.html'
       controller: myComponentCtrl
})


myComponentCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'Forecast'];

function myComponentCtrl($scope, Forecast) {/* ... */  }
```